# Abstraction for Database access

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I need to iterate through a list of abstract class's instances which each implements a method to load its data from a database. For simplicity lets say the Abstract class contains only that method:
**Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class AManagerBase
{
    public abstract Response InitiateManagerResources(IDataManager dbManager);
}
```

When a class that derived from this base class is written, the method is implemented by calling the `IDataManager`'s method `ExecuteCommand` which accepts an SQL command to retreive data from that class's table in the DB.
For example:

```
var tableData = dataManager.ExecuteCommand($"SELECT DC.* FROM {CLASS_TABLE_NAME} DC");
```

I want to use some sort of abstraction to the DB access instead of sending SQL command. I read about Repository Pattern, but the problem in my case is that each class that is written in the future will have its own table in the database with its own data and i can't add entities to the shared module each time a class is written.
The bottom line is that i want to be able to replcae the DB in the future (currently using Access DB) to some other DB (maybe xml file) without changing all the written libraries.
Some more examples:

```
// Independent library A.dll
// A.dll has a table named A_Table in the DB
public class ClassA : AManagerBase
{
    public override Response InitiateManagerResources(IDataManager dbManager)
    {
        var loadedData = dbManager.ExecuteCommand("Select ...");
        // create my own defined entities from the returned data
    }
}

// Independent library B.dll
// B.dll has two tables named B_Table1 and B_Table2 in the DB
public class ClassB : AManagerBase
{
    public override Response InitiateManagerResources(IDataManager dbManager)
    {
        var loadedData = dbManager.ExecuteCommand("Select ...");
        // create my own defined entities from the returned data
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use some ORM and just switch then to another DB provider?

Comment: wouldn't Entity Framework handle this for you ?

Comment: @kamo can you please show a simple example, so i will understand the idea?

Comment: @auburg thanks but Entity framework doesn't work with MS access DB and if in the future i will want to change DB to say an XML file it is also not supported. Plus the tables are added manually to the DB every time a new derived class is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, in your dbManager ExecuteCommand method i would remove the SQL like SELECT statement and have that done internally rather than passed in by the client classes in their InitiateManagerResources calls. I would have a configuration file that maps each dll to whatever table(s) they're accessing i.e.

A=A_Table
B=B_Table1,Table2
...

When each class from that dll is instantiated,either pass in the table list in the constructor or have each class read it in themselves. Then pass this table list as a string to the dbManager.ExecuteCommand method i.e.

dbManager.ExecuteCommand("A_Table")

Hopefully the db manager should have enough information to execute the query and return results. If / when you move to XML, then the only thing that changes is the format of the data in your mapping file (depending on the layout of your XML file). You could have another implementation of IDataManager that understood how to parse this XML file (using Linq to XML perhaps?) but your client classes wouldn't change because they're just passing in data from your mapping file. Hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. I've tried to find a more convenient solution but apperently i can't find one. I've ended up using part of you answer. Each dll class init method will call the ExecuteCommand method with "section" names and the data manager will use those names to pull those names from the Database (and in the future from the xml file). I've skipped the mapping file part for now. If we will decide to transfer to xml files we'll keep the same structure as the existing tables. Thank you.